# In App Purchase Section is not visible under Features on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

[image]I have an app that is not submitted for review but I am unable to see the in-app purchase section for the same in Features. I have created an IAP product which is also lost after the Agreement/tax registration process. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select...

- Appstore from top
- On left side at bottom There is a section of in-app purchase
- Select **Manage** option from in-App purchase section to add in-app purchases.

Please refer to the following image so add in-app purchase for an app.

[image]

Comment: Getting black space from clicking manage. Not able to access this area

Comment: i can't see MANAGE. Comparing to your screenshot - I have FEATURES in place of In-App Purchases. Under features there's in-app-purchases. But I think it's not the same as the original one. I can't associate a binary with my IAP.